# Does the MSYS2 version of emacs support X server?

Tags: emacs, msys2

MSYS2 has three versions of emacs. Only the `msys/emacs` version supports `term` mode and other shell related features. The `mingw32` and `mingw64` versions only support the inconvenient `shell` and `eshell` mode.

However, the `msys` version does not seem to support GUI. In Cygwin it was possible to access GUI by installing an X server. Does the MSYS2 version supports X server? How to configure this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use cygwin, it now offers a cygwin version of emacs that supports a native Windows gui (emacs-w32); no need for an X-server!